# The rules of the scope of for loops in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, scope

This is a problem I've had a problem with for a long time, and it'd be nice if I could finally get an answer to this. My instructor at school always seems to comes up with a craft solution around this, but I need to know how to fix it.

```
/**
 * This program lets you enter your students names and grades
 * 
 * @author (Austin) 
 * @version (1.0.0)
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Tester
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("How many students do you have?");
    int numOfStudents = kb.nextInt();

    String studentName[] = new String [numOfStudents];
    int studentGrade[] = new int[numOfStudents];

    System.out.println ("Please enter student name, then hit enter. Then enter student grade.");
    int x;
    int y;
    for (x = 0; x <= numOfStudents - 1; x++)
    {
        String name = kb.next();
        studentName[x] = name;
        for (y = 0; y <= 0; y++)
        {
            int grade = kb.nextInt();
            studentGrade[y] = grade;
        }
        if (x != numOfStudents -1)
        {
            System.out.println ("");
            System.out.println ("Next Student:");
            System.out.println ("");
        }
    }

    System.out.println ("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println ("1. Find class average\n2. Find student grade");
    int user = kb.nextInt();

    Grade_Methods g1 = new Grade_Methods(); 
    int z;

    if (user == 1)
    {
        for (z = 0; z <=numOfStudents - 1; z++)
        {
            int a =+ studentGrade[z];
        }
        g1.gradeAverage(a,numOfStudents);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is at the bottom of the code, inside the if statement. This program is meant to help me better understand arrays, and I don't know how to pull the data out of them except using a for loop. My problem is, when I try to store all the values from array `studentGrade` into int `a` as a total value for all grades, the line below, where I try to call it into a method, won't recognize that int `a` has been declared.

Comment: The variable declared inside the { } has scope inside that only, ex    { int a } , a's scope will be inside that { }, in your problem declare int a  ouside like int a=0; for(some condition){};

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `a` variable prior to the loop :

```
    int a = 0;
    for (z = 0; z <=numOfStudents - 1; z++)
    {
        a += studentGrade[z];
    }
```

This way it remains within scope after the loop ends, and you can access its value.

Comment: i tried that prior, and it didn't work, however when you use the int a = 0; it worked. why is that?

Comment: @DiamondBrook variables declared inside the block of the loop exist only until the loop ends. variables declared before the loop's blcok remain after the loop ends. That's why you have to declare `a` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int a` has been declared inside the scope of the for loop. If you want to access the variable outside the loop, use this:

```
int a = 0;
for (z = 0; z <=numOfStudents - 1; z++)
{
    a += studentGrade[z];
}
g1.gradeAverage(a,numOfStudents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the int inside the for loop, meaning that it won't be accessible outside of that for loop. A workaround might be something like this.

```
if (user == 1) {
    int a = 0;
    for(z = 0; z <= numOfStudents - 1; z++) {
        a += studentGrade[z];
    }
    g1.gradeAverage(a, numOfStudents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope is about visibility. A variable not visible outside of its scope. For example:

```
int b;  

for ... {
   int a = 1; 
   b = 2;  
}

int c = b;
int d = a; // error
```

In this case b is declared outside of the for loop, so an assignment made to b is visible outside of the for loop. Using that value outside of the for loop is fine.

On the other hand, the assignment from a is illegal because a was *declared* inside the for loop. It therefore is no longer available once you exit the loop, so there's no "a" available to assign to d.